# Testing Google Cloud Build cloudbuild.yaml locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I want to use google cloud build, to build, test and deploy my Java Application, however, I am new to Cloud Build and I see it is run using steps scripts, How can I run (test) locally the script before running on Google Cloud Build ?

Comment: You can use the local builder but it's not supported anymore. You can give it a try anyway https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-build-local

Comment: In addition, the new version of Cloud Build which is still cooking and available in alpha will be based on Tekton and you will be able to test it more easily. Until then, there is no magic solution...